# How to group by multiple columns a dataset

Tags: apache-spark

I am trying to group-by a dataset by some of its columns like so :

```
        dF.write().partitionBy("col0", "col1","col3").saveAsTable("t4");
        Dataset<Row> tableDF=spark.sql("select * from t4");
        Dataset<Row> newDF = tableDF.toDF();
```

But `newDF` schema is not matching the one i want, so i should change the resulting schema, how to achieve this ?

PS : otherwise how to use `orderBy` to achieve the `partitionBy` ?

EDIT : from a random dataset the desired output (groupedBy `"Hour"` & `"Category"`) would look like the following:

```
+----+--------+----------+
|Hour|Category|TotalValue|
+----+--------+----------+
|   0|   cat26|      30.9|
|   0|   cat26|      22.1|
|   0|   cat26|      19.6|
|   0|   cat26|       1.3|
|   1|   cat26|      28.5|
|   1|   cat26|      26.8|
|   1|   cat26|      12.6|
|   1|   cat26|       5.3|
|   2|   cat27|      39.6|
|   2|   cat40|      29.7|
|   2|   cat40|      27.9|
|   2|   cat40|       9.8|
|   3|   cat40|      35.6|
| ...|    ....|      ....|
+----+--------+----------+
```

EDIT2 : an input sample would look like the following :

```
+----+--------+----------+
|Hour|Category|TotalValue|
+----+--------+----------+
|   0|   cat26|      30.9|
|   2|   cat13|      22.1|
|   0|   cat95|      19.6|
|   1|  cat105|       1.3|
|   1|   cat67|      28.5|
|   2|    cat4|      26.8|
|   1|   cat13|      12.6|
|   1|   cat23|       5.3|
|   1|   cat56|      39.6|
|   2|   cat40|      29.7|
|   0|  cat187|      27.9|
|   1|   cat68|       9.8|
|   3|    cat8|      35.6|
| ...|    ....|      ....|
+----+--------+----------+
```

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to SO! In order to help you, can you edit an example of the DataSet input and what the desired (I suppose) DataFrame output would look like?

Comment: Sure! see my EDIT !

Comment: Is your edit showing the DataSet that you want to do the multicolumn groupby or what you want to have _after_ the groupby? Because your example would have aggregated values from `TotalValue` like `[30.9, 22.1, 19.6, 1.3]` for Hour `0` and Category `cat26`, and so on, and so on.

Comment: The edit is showing the result i want to get from a random dataset, totalValue here is just for the example but the focus is on columns Hour & Category, thanks

Comment: Can you please put an example of the "input" (or what would `tableDF` look like) and its schema in order to have a clearer image on the issue?

Comment: See my second edit pls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you kind of mix up `orderBy` with `groupBy`, since you really need the first one, but the title of the question mentions the second one.

For Spark 3.0.1+ you can either:

- use the `orderBy` Spark method that takes one or more columns as parameters or
- write a simple SQL query with a typical `order by` statement.

You can use either of these like this (with `_1` and `_2` being the 1st and 2nd column of the `input` DataSet respectively):

```
def main(args: Array[String]): Unit =
{
    // run locally, for testing purposes
    val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Two Column Order By").setMaster("local")

    val spark = SparkSession.builder.config(conf).getOrCreate()

    // implicit for the toDS() method
    import spark.implicits._

    // test input Dataset based on your example
    val input = Seq(
                        (0, "cat26", 30.9),
                        (2, "cat13", 22.1),
                        (0, "cat95", 19.6),
                        (1, "cat105", 1.3),
                        (1, "cat67", 28.5),
                        (2, "cat4", 26.8),
                        (1, "cat13", 12.6),
                        (1, "cat23", 5.3),
                        (1, "cat56", 39.6),
                        (2, "cat40", 29.7),
                        (0, "cat187", 27.9),
                        (1, "cat68", 9.8),
                        (3, "cat8", 35.6)
                    ).toDS()

    // using Spark's orderBy method
    val test1 = input.orderBy("_1", "_2")
    test1.show()

    // writing a simple SQL query
    input.createOrReplaceTempView("test_table")
    val test2 = spark.sql("SELECT * FROM test_table ORDER BY _1, _2")
    test2.show()
}
```

The output of both `test1` and `test2` will look like this (notice how the second column is ordered as a `String`, so of course `cat1*` will be considered alphabetically "smaller" than `cat2*`):

```
+---+------+----+
| _1|    _2|  _3|
+---+------+----+
|  0|cat187|27.9|
|  0| cat26|30.9|
|  0| cat95|19.6|
|  1|cat105| 1.3|
|  1| cat13|12.6|
|  1| cat23| 5.3|
|  1| cat56|39.6|
|  1| cat67|28.5|
|  1| cat68| 9.8|
|  2| cat13|22.1|
|  2|  cat4|26.8|
|  2| cat40|29.7|
|  3|  cat8|35.6|
+---+------+----+
```